# Books of examples of positions for beginners (Texas Hold'em)

Tags: texas-hold-em, books

I am new to poker and I am looking for books to learn the basics of no limit Texas Hold'em from, however the resources I have found so far explain the basic principles, but without examples that would let me test if I have understood how to apply them. I want to know if there are any books that are specifically about giving you lots of positions to test your understanding, and which are aimed at a beginner.

(Note: I am very new to poker, so I apologise if the terminology is incorrect.)

Answer (score 2):

Harrington on Hold'em is an excellent book that I still think holds up well as an introduction to good solid poker strategy. One thing I think this book does well is the examples and scenarios it gives. The book wasn't aimed at complete novices when it was written but in comparison to todays game I actually think as long as you understand the basics (what poker is, how to play, positions, etc) it's a great starting point. This book will not make you a poker crusher in the modern game, but it will teach solid foundations which is still more than many live player actually have.

Master Micro Stakes Poker by Alton Hardin is specifically tailored at micro stake games and is an excellent beginners book. It covers a lot, things you might not consider you should consider like how do you profile players, how do you actually study poker. It's clear and logical and microstakes are a the likely place you'll start playing poker so relevant.

Many books by Jonathan Little. He has released many books, some are very specific but others are more general. Little is well respected in poker and his writing style is very straight forward, logical and no messing about. Wouldn't start with his stuff as it may require you to have some fundamentals in place already.

Comment: I will add, books while useful are more limited in the modern game. You'd be best following forums and content online for more up to date. Books are great for the fundamentals though!